# Having trouble with Linq list sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Good evening.

I have a list of a class that I would like to index for different reasons, one being that I would like to read the data in different orders at different times. The trouble I am having is that I cannot get my head around sorting with LINQ.

The class I have in my list is similar to this (this is a smaller version)

```
List<SalesRecord> Records = new List<SalesRecord>();
class SalesRecord
{
    public Int16 SalesID { get; set; }
    public Int32 Invoice { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookoutDate { get; set; }
}
```

The count size of Records is roughly 500,000

My thoughts were to create a couple of lists that would reference each item in Records in a particular order

Eg:

```
List<int> BookoutDateIndex;
List<int> InvoiceIndex;

Records[BookoutDateIndex[0]].BookoutDate // Oldest date
Records[BookoutDateIndex[1]].BookoutDate // Second oldest date
                                         // etc
```

Based on the information I have seen, the closest I have found that almost does what I want is this...

```
// Copy dates to new list
List<DateTime> BookoutDates = new List<DateTime>();

for (int salesRecordIndex = 0; salesRecordIndex < records.Count; salesRecordIndex++)
    BookoutDates.Add(Records[salesRecordIndex].BookoutDate);

// Sort list

var sorted = Indexes.BookoutDates
    .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(x, i))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Although this works, I don't want the actual date in the Index and I don't want to have to copy the dates in a new list beforehand.

I realize this would be easier to do by loading the data into something like a Access database, but I prefer to do it without a database option.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `"I don't want the actual date in the Index"` - Then what *do* you want in the resulting list?  I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  If you just want to order the `records` by `BookoutDate` then that would simply be: `records.OrderBy(r => r.BookoutDate)`.  Can you clarify what you want different from that?

Comment: really seem to be overcomplicating this. Just `Records.OrderBy` what you need

Comment: Not quite sure what you want the end data  to hold, or why you would want two lists of ~500k records, i would have thought it would be best to just sort the original list into order when you need it in that order.

Comment: You seem to basically describe a simple OrderBy(x => x.BookOutDate) and adding unnecessary complexity? From a database viewpoint, one would expect SaledId to be a primary key but it is not in your case (Int16 for 500,000 records?). Would you elaborate what you are trying to do. If you think it would be easier to use a database instead, then probably you wouldn't want to use something like access but Sqlite (embedded and could use in memory database).

Answer (score 2):

Summary of what you want: a list of the indexes of the main list sorted by some field on the main list?

As LINQ's `OrderBy` doesn't actually change the input, one ends up with your:

> ```
> var sorted = Indexes.BookoutDates
>                      .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(x, i))
>                      .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
>                      .ToList();
> ```

You are using a value type (`KeyValuePair`) to reduce the allocations that an anonymous type would bring. But there is no need to create a separate list of just the date you need first. Just take from the underlying list to start with.

And the `Key` property of the `KeyValuePair` is the *first* constructor parameter.

```
var sorted = Records
    .Select((r, x) => new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(r.BookoutDate, x))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your summary of what I want is correct. However your answer does not work for me.

Comment: Your summary of what I want is correct. However your answer does not work for me. The second line products an error saying cannot convert from SalesRecord to System.DateTime and int does not contain a defination for BookoutDate

Comment: @GrantMcConville: That was just a typo, the object and the indexer were swapped in the `.Select()`.  Try the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you just want:

```
var sorted = Records
    .OrderBy(x => x.BookoutDate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: From what I have tried of this, it will copy the whole list to a new variable. Not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: With Linq, these extension methods return a new Enumerable. You can reassign this to Records, or whatever you need. But your example is copying everything to some sort of list, then creating a list of KeyValue pairs. This is much simpler.